# WCF Configuration for https and JSON Post

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, post

As it normally happens, I accidentally overwrote my web.config file this morning that has my WCF settings already working perfectly. As you would expect, no backup...shame shame shame on me.

That being said, I can't seem to get my configuration working again.
Here is the error that I keep getting back from IIS/ASP.NET

> The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to
>   a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between
>   sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender
>   and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport, None).

Here is an overview of what I have setup.

My Web Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="Binding1" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
  <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="10000000" />
  <security mode="Transport"></security>
  </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior>
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
  <service name="MyService">
  <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" contract="IMyService" />
  </service>
  </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the declaration in my Service Contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/SSMX", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
sqlStudio_Table_Permissions SSMX(string TableName);
```

Sadly I just can't seem to remember what I did in my previous configuration to make this work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found the issue myself.

Comment: I was missing behaviorConfiguration in my EndPoint that pointed to a webHTTP binding